# Compute difference and update value in place in javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, in-place

The following snippet does it job, but it looks clumsy to me:

```
var lastFrame = performance.now();
function elapsedMillis(){
  var now = performance.now();
  var elapsedTime = lastFrame - now;
  lastFrame = now;
  return elapsedTime;
}
```

Every time it's called it computes the elapsed time since last call. `performance.now()` should be called only once, since it's the most expensive operation.

I got this one, but I think there might be a better solution out there:

```
var lastFrame = performance.now();
function elapsedMillis(){
  var now = performance.now();
  var elapsedTime;
  return ([elapsedTime,lastFrame]=[now-lastFrame,now])[0];
}
```

`elapsedTime` is not really needed.

Is there a better way of writing such an assignment?

**Edit:**

I'm using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility) here, which is apparently only supported by firefox for the time being. I wasn't aware that I could also do something like this:

```
var lastFrame = performance.now();
function elapsedMillis(){
  var now = performance.now();
  return ([,lastFrame]=[now-lastFrame,now])[0];
}
```

Comment: I think the first way is clearer, but maybe I'm just not yet used to seeing destructuring assignment in JavaScript (and I'm not rushing to use it myself since it isn't supported in all browsers yet). But "better" is a matter of opinion...

Answer (score 0):

the firstone I think, could be a way to control the elapsed time from the *lastFrame* assuming that *performance* is a **Date**...

The second example, instead, is totally wrong... because it ends with an **invalid left-hand side in assignment** and throws a Bad Assignment Error...
In stackoverflow are many topics on top of this error...

Here my way, assuming that is singletone:

```js
var elapsedTime = (function(performance) {
  var lastCall = performance.now();
  console.log(lastCall);
  
  return function() {
    var now = performance.now();
    var elapsed = now - lastCall;
    
    // reassigning lastCall each time you call the function make the function work with the last invocation, if you want to calc the elapsed time from the first invocation you have to not-reassign the lastCall variable!
    lastCall = now;
    
    return elapsed;
  };
})(window.Date);
```

Comment: The question is about the variable assignment and return call. Your answer is exactly like the first version I had. Furthermore the second one is a technique called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility) defined in ECMAScript 6